# Vertical alignment of sub-element

Tags: css, html

I have a block element with fixed height(depends on the height other surrounding blocks and equal to the height of the highest of these), but height of content is less. How I can to align my **div.bottom** element on the bottom? Sorry for my bad English(

```
<div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
    </p>

    <div class="bottom">
        Read more
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? so that we can help you further.

Comment: Where is your css? and what is div height?

Comment: JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/w1pkmyhq/

Comment: Use `display:inline:block` and `vertical-align:bottom`.

Comment: It does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/w1pkmyhq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative position to the parent element and absolute to the bottom element. Specify the bottom as 0 for the bottom element. That will make sure the element is in bottom. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8ynbpmhb/).

```js
function setEqualHeight(columns) {
  var tallestcolumn = 0;
  columns.each(function() {
    currentHeight = $(this).height();

    if (currentHeight > tallestcolumn) {
      tallestcolumn = currentHeight;
    }
  });

  columns.height(tallestcolumn);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  setEqualHeight($(".container > article"));
});
```

```css
section {
  padding: 0 6% 0 6%;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
section article {
  width: 28.6%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0.7%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
section img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
section article div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h2>This is H2</h2>

  <div class="container">
    <article>
      <img src="img/1A.png" alt="1A_icecream_image">

      <h3>First H2</h3>

      <p>
        Знакомый с детства вкус беззаботной радости того времени, когда все деревья были большими, а чувства — светлыми.
      </p>

      <div>Read more</div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="img/parsley.png" alt="parsley_image">

      <h3>Second H2</h3>

      <p>
        Нестандартное сочетание нейма с прилагательными, входящими в обозначение товарной группы.
      </p>

      <div>Read more</div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="img/darida.png" alt="darida_aqua_image">

      <h3>Third H2</h3>

      <p>
        Компания Fabula разработала концепт этикеток 8 SKU, сделав основным акцентом плашку, которая поддерживает единый цельный образ всего ряда.
      </p>

      <div>Read more</div>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem:

```
<div style="height: 400px; width: 250px; border: 1px solid black">
    <div style="display: table-cell; height: 400px; vertical-align: bottom">
        Some random content.
    </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to wrap teh content in a div that has table cell display and set the vertical align to bottom.

I prefer this kind of technic rather than absolute positioning that usually carry additional issues.

look at this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w1pkmyhq/2/

I modified a little your markup so it trenders the expected result

Comment: Nope. I don't know which height of my current block. It's depends on the height other surrounding blocks: https://jsfiddle.net/w1pkmyhq/